# Preserve Autocomplete results when using back button

Tags: android, ios, mobile, webview, autocomplete

We are designing a new feature in a mobile app, accessible through a web view.

When users tap the new view from the app menu, a web view would open, showing a page containing a search form with a single text input to search a collection of items by name.

This field would be auto-completed in a fashion similar to how the Gmail app auto-completes an e-mail address from the user's contacts when composing a new mail message.

In our case, when the user chooses one of the auto-completed results, the web view loads the details of the selected result.

My question is if it is possible to achieve that when the user hits the back button, he/she returns to the previous page, **but with the auto-complete proposals still active**.

**Edit 1**

The goal of my question is to find out if this can be achieved with standard technologies, like web components combined with something else, or if a working implementation already exists provided by a component collection.

If not, I can imagine that an approach along the lines of what GIJOW suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the input content and store it in a variable:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <input id="query" type="text" value="My query text"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Swift

```
 let myValue = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('myId').value")
```

And after you set if on view controller load again, for example:

```
<form>
 Query <input type="text" id="query" name="Query" width="20"/>
</form>
```

In Swift -

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
 let html = String(format: "%@%@%@", "document.getElementById('query').value = ", myValue, ";")
 self.wbView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(html)
}
```

Or if you want to keep also the results, you can store the input text and pass it by querystring when load the page again.

Comment: If I'm correct, the idea is to store the results on the webview side (using Swift in case of iOS) and re-inject it in the page once reloaded via back action.
However, my question is aimed at discovering existing solutions as web-components or similar; I'm gonna clarify my question now

Comment: Then I don't know but in this case we have to remove your mobile tags as if I understood you will/want to implement it on web side. Mobile has nothing to do in this case

Comment: I'm leaving the tag mobile, because I'm not sure if webview provides all platform features accessible by a full web-browser, e.g. HTML5 local storage which could be used for an approach similar to what u suggested  to do via Swift